SignalR Disconnects after trying to call a method
The connection works fine but when I try to call a method it ends up calling the disconnect method with an erorr saying it can't find "ParseMessage". I have 2 separate .NET 7 apps. One for server and 1 for client. This is all just a test to get methods being called.
When I press the Start Timer button that's when it disconnects me.
Server hub:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace SignalRTest;

public class MyHub : Hub
{
    // This dictionary could map user connections to active timers if needed for multiple users
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, CancellationTokenSource> UserTimers = new Dictionary<string, CancellationTokenSource>();

    // This method is called when a client successfully connects to the hub.
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        // You can retrieve the connection ID or perform any startup logic here
        string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        Console.WriteLine($"Client connected: {connectionId}");

        // You can also send a message back to the client on connection
        await Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", $"Welcome! Your connection ID is {connectionId}");

        // Call the base class method to ensure proper connection handling
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    // This method is called when a client disconnects from the hub.
    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
    {
        string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        Console.WriteLine($"Client disconnected: {connectionId}");

        if (exception != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Disconnected due to an error: {exception.Message}");
        }

        if (UserTimers.ContainsKey(connectionId))
        {
            UserTimers[connectionId].Cancel();
            UserTimers.Remove(connectionId);
        }

        // Call the base class method to ensure proper disconnection handling
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }

    // Method called by the client to start the timer
    public async Task StartTimer()
    {
        var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

        // Ensure only one timer per connection
        if (UserTimers.ContainsKey(connectionId))
        {
            await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", "Timer already running.");
            return;
        }

        // Create a cancellation token for this user's timer
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        UserTimers[connectionId] = cts;

        await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", "Timer started.");

        // Start a loop to send updates every 5 seconds
        int counter = 0;
        while (!cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            counter += 5;
            await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ReceiveTimerUpdate", counter);
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(5000, cts.Token); // Wait 5 seconds
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                break; // If the task is canceled, exit the loop
            }
        }
    }

    // Method called by the client to stop the timer
    public async Task StopTimer()
    {
        var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        if (UserTimers.ContainsKey(connectionId))
        {
            UserTimers[connectionId].Cancel();
            UserTimers.Remove(connectionId);
            await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", "Timer stopped.");
        }
        else
        {
            await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", "No active timer found.");
        }
    }
}

Client Index.html
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SignalR Timer Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/microsoft-signalr/8.0.7/signalr.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="startButton">Start Timer</button>
    <button id="stopButton">Stop Timer</button>
    <div id="timerOutput"></div>

    <script>
        const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("https://localhost:7156/my-hub", {
                withCredentials: true // Allows credentials like cookies or authentication tokens to be sent
            })
            .withAutomaticReconnect()
            .build();

        connection.start().then(() => {
            console.log("Connected to SignalR");
        }).catch(err => console.error(err));

        document.getElementById("startButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
            connection.invoke("StartTimer").catch(err => console.error(err));
        });

        document.getElementById("stopButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
            connection.invoke("StopTimer").catch(err => console.error(err));
        });

        connection.on("ReceiveTimerUpdate", (counter) => {
            document.getElementById("timerOutput").innerText = `Time: ${counter} seconds`;
        });

        connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (message) => {
            console.log(message);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

With logging enabled the server shows this when I click StartTimer button:

Client side when logging added and I press StartTimer button


The ParseMessage method in the error message seems to be a custom method. Please check your two .net7 projects carefully to make sure that the client has a method to listen to ParseMessage and that the server has a call to ParseMessage.

From the current server and client code, there is no ParseMessage method. My understanding is that you may have confused the codes in the two .net7 projects.

In addition, there is a problem with your MyHub code. After clicking Start Timer, the method in MyHub cannot be triggered. This is a modified example that may help you.

And you also can enbale asp.net-core signalr client/server side logging feature, here is the sample, you can find detailed error message.

@JasonPan Yeah I think the ParseMessage is coming from a Json dll that SignalR is using to parse the message coming in from the client. What I'm seeing when I look at the SignalR payload from the client is that it just has the id=[id value] and that's it. My understanding is that SignalR is supposed to have some json structure of what method and params it needs the server to call but I don't see that being sent at all from the client.

Thanks for your update @user441521, could you share the .csproj file and let me check the packages, thanks

This is a server side error when a code in one assembly tries to execute method in another assembly. According to the message it is not related to SignalR itself. The connection is closed because of server side exception.
This could be because of inconsistent packages versions. I'd suggest to check if the major versions are 7 for both the Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common and Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json packages.

I didn't even have Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json installed. I installed that (both are version 8) and then the method got called. Why wouldn't that be a transitive package if it's required?

I can guess this is because you can use multiple protocols for SignalR, so they not include assembly for particular protocol by default.
